# How to download Android TV emulator with Play Store

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

According to this blogpost https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/6-new-ways-to-engage-with-users-on.html it is now possible to have an Android TV Emulator with Play Store.

I have no idea how it can be set up though - please see my Android SDK setup below. Has anyone of you managed to get it to work?

SDK Platforms
[image: SDK Platforms]

SDK Tools
[image: SDK Tools]

Emulator view
[image: Emulator view]

Comment: I think you won't be able to do so because android studio doesn't show any image with play store for tv emulator device.

Comment: @KaranMehta this is correct, but how do I make it appear?

Comment: It is a functionality given by android studio, we cannot show it manually

Comment: @KaranMehta - sorry I am not sure what you have in mind. Can you rephrase your answer? Do you mean that there is some other way in which I can create/open such emulator?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Play Store services are available on any API 29 Android TV emulator without any indication in the "Play Store" column in AVD Manager. This is very confusing.